# How to fix inAppBrowser open error in ionic V4.12.0 (issue in real device only)

Tags: angular, ionic-framework

i tried to open external url using InAppBrowser from "ionic-native/in-app-browser". It's working fine while debugging in browser but error in debug with real device.  error given bellow

> ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Java exception was raised
>   during method invocation Error: Java exception was raised during
>   method invocation
>       at androidExec (cordova.js:960)
>       at module.exports (inappbrowser.js:113)
>       at new InAppBrowserObject (vendor.js:84078)
>       at InAppBrowser.push../node_modules/@ionic-native/in-app-browser/ngx/index.js.InAppBrowser.create (vendor.js:84119)
>       at PaymentComponent. (default~order-order-module~products-order-order-info-order-info-module~products-order-takeaway-page-~77b4b037.js:408)
>       at step (vendor.js:161589)
>       at Object.next (vendor.js:161570)
>       at fulfilled (vendor.js:161560)
>       at ZoneDelegate.push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate.invoke
>   (polyfills.js:3239)
>       at Object.onInvoke (vendor.js:59091)
>       at resolvePromise (polyfills.js:3700)
>       at polyfills.js:3610
>       at rejected (vendor.js:161561)
>       at ZoneDelegate.push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate.invoke
>   (polyfills.js:3239)
>       at Object.onInvoke (vendor.js:59091)
>       at ZoneDelegate.push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate.invoke
>   (polyfills.js:3238)
>       at Zone.push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.Zone.run (polyfills.js:2998)
>       at polyfills.js:3758
>       at ZoneDelegate.push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate.invokeTask
>   (polyfills.js:3271)
>       at Object.onInvokeTask (vendor.js:59082)

```
import { InAppBrowser } from '@ionic-native/in-app-browser/ngx';

constructor(        
        private iab: InAppBrowser
    ) {
        const browser = this.iab.create('https://ionicframework.com/');
    browser.close()
    //or 
     const browser1 = this.iab.create(https://ionicframework.com/);
         browser1.show();
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my app there is no need to show the browser, and especially not to close it right after creation..

Can you try the '_system' argument to open a browser with the system default? That might explain the error on a real device

```
const browser = this.iab.create('https://ionicframework.com/', '_system');
```

Comment: Thanks @RobrechtVM.